Film noir involving a smuggling ring connected to a tour of Chinatown
I'm looking to identify this black-and-white film from the 30s to the early 40s. I remember the last act of this film clearly, but not the title.
The detective and his secretary/sidekick join a tour of "the underside of Chinatown", through the shipping tunnels under the city. The tour guide (very possibly played by Allen Jenkins, but don't hold me to it) surreptitiously opens a door to a storage room, where four cheongsam-clad Chinese ladies are huddled around a table. The guide explains they're playing Fan-Tan, and they're kept down here to remain safe from the eyes of men, and must never speak. He claims if they ever spoke, let alone to an American, they'd be whisked off and killed in an inscrutable ceremony. As he closes the door, the ladies start chatting (in perfect English): "OK, girls, he's gone, I knock with three..."
At the end of the tour, they emerge in a gift shop (of course), where everyone is gifted with a box of Chinese tea. The detective finds it interesting that while everyone grabs a box from a display on the counter, one man is handed a box from UNDER the counter. After a brief scuffle, the box is revealed to contain the McGuffin.
Ringing a bell for anyone?

was it a black and white or color movie?

b&w, 30s of early 40s I'd guess.

Do any of these ring a bell? Allen Jenkins filmography?

Was the detective famous for the time (Charlie Chan, Mr Moto, etc?)

It wasn't a "name" detective that I can recall, no, if I could remember who played the detective, it'd be very helpful, but I can't.
